# Crash Dump Analysis: how to find the module and instruction causing the crash

Tags: crash-dumps, ildasm

I have a crash dump file and I want to identify the exact instruction where the crash occurred, more precisely in 'System_Messaging_ni+60e4e', because I suspect of a MSMQ issue.

```
Function                                     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3   Source 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+58                 e0434f4d     00000001     00000001    
mscorwks!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+300e1  015c95dc     00000000     00000000    
mscorwks!GetMetaDataInternalInterface+29d15  00000000     00000000     0164d854    
System_Messaging_ni+814aa                    00000000     00000000     0141aeb0    
System_Messaging_ni+60e4e                    0061ec0c     73d2f845     8e1d9768    
mscorwks+f830                                01611664     09d4f328     734402ff
```

My understanding is that 'System_Messaging_ni+60e4e' means 'instruction at byte offset 0x60e4e from the beginning of module 'System_Messaging_ni'.

How do I determine the exact DLL file referenced by 'System_Messaging_ni'? I could not find any System.Message.ni.dll in my system. What does the _ni suffix mean?
How can I tell if the instruction at the offset is IL or native code?
If the instruction is in IL, can I use ILDASM to spot the exact location?

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

that probably has something to do with .Net

I know the numbers are all in hexadecimal.

I noticed there's no source column.

you might want to try a version that had debug symbols (looks like you already are because it's not numbers only). if that's what you are using, hmm. maybe the only thing left is to start analyzing the parameters fed into the functions and see where things went awry.

I usually start by generating a .map file when I compile my code. this generates the list /offsets/ into the codebase, with which you can determine which function (in case you just get a crashdump with only numbers) the crash occurred in. (like in which system call maybe).

guesses for ni:

- network interface
- .net interface (my guess)
- non-?
- ?-idl (doubt this, IDL/MIDL usually specifies the interface, not used for most end-user-developers unless you are creating an interface)